# Is there a way to programmatically center a view from one button to another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I wonder if I programmatically can center a view from one element to another.

The screenshot under explains it.

If I click on "Sort2" I want to animate the view from Sort2 to be centered under Sort1 instead

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your selector for Sort2 button, add the line

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    sort2View.center = CGPointMake(sort1View.center.x, sort1View.center.y + 50)
}];
```

Another much cleaner approach would be to add `UIConstraint`s.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to animate with CGPointMake but its really hard to guess the right amount it should be moved. Do you have any very simple example using UIConstraints?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't need to guess. You need to calculate how distance you want to put between the 2 views and how much size do the two views have. Because to put the UIConstraints, you would still need to do some calculations.

Comment: I am making them bigger depending on device, so UIConstraints would be nice. But I will set some fixed sizes instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way with using layout constraints. You should give center constraint between Sort2 and your view and set it's priority to High. After that give center constraint between Sort1 and your view and set it's priority to Low. After that you just need to change their priorities use this code. (In code, yourView is your whole view including these three views)

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [yourView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```